# Combine an append query with regular queries in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following 3 queries. The first one takes the relevant data from the total amount of data:

```
SELECT 
    (n()-1)*[Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo] & ' - ' & n()*[Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo] & " kW" AS Bin, 
    q_DataLimited.POW001, 
    q_DataLimited.WSP001, 
    q_DataLimited.POW002, 
    q_DataLimited.WSP002
FROM q_DataLimited
WHERE 
    (
        ((q_DataLimited.POW001)>(n()-1)*[Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo] 
            And (q_DataLimited.POW001)<n()*[Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo]
        )
        AND (([Forms]![f_Main]![BinOnTurbine])='Reference Turbine') 
        AND ((q_DataLimited.[VG's])='Without')
    ) 
    OR 
    (
        (
            (q_DataLimited.POW002)>(n()-1)*[Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo] 
                And (q_DataLimited.POW002)<n()*[Forms]![f_Main]![PowerBinCombo]
        ) 
        AND (([Forms]![f_Main]![BinOnTurbine])='Power Curve Upgraded Turbine') 
        AND ((q_DataLimited.[VG's])='Without')
    );
```

and a query calculating Averages and StDev:

```
SELECT q_PowerBinned.Bin, Avg(q_PowerBinned.POW001) AS AvgOfPOW001, StDev(q_PowerBinned.POW001) AS StDevOfPOW001, Avg(q_PowerBinned.WSP001) AS AvgOfWSP001, StDev(q_PowerBinned.WSP001) AS StDevOfWSP001, Avg(q_PowerBinned.POW002) AS AvgOfPOW002, StDev(q_PowerBinned.POW002) AS StDevOfPOW002, Avg(q_PowerBinned.WSP002) AS AvgOfWSP002, StDev(q_PowerBinned.WSP002) AS StDevOfWSP002, Count(q_PowerBinned.Bin) AS CountOfBin
FROM q_PowerBinned
GROUP BY q_PowerBinned.Bin;
```

I want to move the values into a table. For that, I use the append query in Access. The SQL looks like:

```
INSERT INTO t_Average_Stored ( Bin, PowAvg001, WindAvg001, PowAvg002, WindAvg002, n_samples, PowDev001, WindDev001, PowDev002, WindDev002 )
SELECT q_Average_Temp.Bin, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfPOW001, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfWSP001, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfPOW002, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfWSP002, q_Average_Temp.CountOfBin, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfPOW001, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfWSP001, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfPOW002, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfWSP002
FROM q_Average_Temp;
```

How it this combined into one SQL?

My SQL is not strong yet, so I struggle with combining some queries to optimize them. I would appreciate a brief description of the reasoning behind the answer so I will be able to apply it to other similar SQL statements.

Thank you in advance.

Emil.

Can this be done smarter/faster?

Examples of what I use it for:

[image: 11]
[image: 22]

Comment: Why do you need this? The third table clearly violated the rules of Normalization, by using Columns as opposed to Rows. Also ignores the fundamental of a Database design, by storing calculated values. Why do you have to do this? Apart from that, why SubQueries? The above should be a bit more efficient in my opinion.

Comment: 1) My experience with "my" software shows  that it is the actual openquery that takes time, despite the action in the query. Therefore, i want to try to combine as much as possible into one, since i don't use intermediate values there. It is one action, in 3 steps. I want it to be 1 action in 1 step, so to speak. 2) I store values because it is an analysis of data. I calculate different things in different ranges and store them to be able to make a visual plot of it as well as some calculations where i need those values. 3) Please elaborate what you mean by violated rules? :)

Comment: For the record, the program should be seen more as an analysis tool than a database, which access is fine for. The problem is that is has become very slow as i built in more functions. I have added a report (PDF) from the tool, so you can see examples of what it calculates, to ease the understanding.

Comment: I cant edit my reply, but i uploaded a few pics of some graphs i make with the tables i store in. (No pdf)

Comment: @PaulFrancis Denormalization of data and storing of calculated values is not always and automatically "wrong". I have been following a few of Emil's recent questions and I agree with what he's trying to do in his particular case. Neither of those things should be done carelessly, but for practical reasons - especially with respect to performance -  they are occasionally necessary.

Comment: @GordThompson, I do try and work out, but at the very first glance the question did strike to me differently. EmilOlsen, I am sure you are in good hands. Good luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining multiple SQL statements into a single "mega query" requires the use of subqueries, something like

```sql
SELECT subquery.Column1, AVG(subquery.Column2) AS AvgOfColumn2 ... 
FROM
    (
        SELECT Column1, Column2, ...
        FROM tablename
        WHERE ...
    ) AS subquery
GROUP BY subquery.Column1
```

However, if you already have the subqueries stored as saved Query objects in Access then I doubt that re-writing the outer query as

```
INSERT INTO newtable ( Column1, ... )
SELECT statsquery.Column1, ...
FROM
    (
        SELECT subquery.Column1, AVG(subquery.Column2) AS AvgOfColumn2 ... 
        FROM
            (
                SELECT Column1, Column2, ...
                FROM tablename
                WHERE ...
            ) AS subquery
        GROUP BY subquery.Column1
    ) AS statsquery
```

is really going to give you much of a performance boost. The effort involved in crunching the numbers probably takes much more time than parsing the SQL code, whether that code comes from one big compound query or a couple of saved QueryDef objects.

Comment: Hi Gord. Once again, thank you for your time. Well, it seems to me like that is the only option for reducing the calculation speed, since the number of queries can not be minimized. However, do you have some general "good manners" in SQL that might make my queries run faster? I thought that clearing tables were causing times issues, but that proved to be very fast when i debugged. The main thing is the actual query. For example the 3 you see up there, takes in total 30 seconds or so to update. They way i update, is to docmd.open "query" followed by a docmd.close. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: @EmilOlsen One thing you could try: Create a table named [t_PowerBinned] to hold the results of your first query and make sure that there is a non-unique index on the [bin] column. Have your first ("selecting relevant rows") query INSERT INTO [t_PowerBinned], and have your second ("stats") query run against [t_PowerBinned] instead of [q_PowerBinned]. Then run your third query as usual. The [t_PowerBinned] table might speed things up because the [bin] column (1) will be static text instead of an expression, and (2) it will have an index on it.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, i will try that now and let you know of any progress!

Comment: It seems that moving the "governing" query into a table and then use the table each time, improved the speed with a factor of 10! Ty Gord, man of the day.